# Codeigniter - Handle Sessions without cookies

Tags: session, codeigniter, get

Some users might not have cookies enabled. Is there a plugin for CI that automatically generates GET-Parameters and parses those parameters (for example in the constructor of a controller)?

What would be a good CI-way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter 3 the session library doesn't use cookies.
In previous CodeIgniter versions “cookie driver” was the only option and the developers of CI have received negative feedback on not providing that option. Listening to feedback from the community, cookie driver was dropped because it is unsafe.
In CI 3 the Session library comes with 4 drivers, or storage engines, that you can use: files, database, redis, memcached.

[www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers)

Comment: This is misleading. CI 3 does not store session variables in the cookie anymore, but it still sets a cookie with the session id.

Answer (score -1):

Should state, that using params in that way would probably not be a good idea, and I've never heard of a plugin doing that.  You'd probably have to deal with routing issues if you did to begin with.  However, CI actually gives you a way to store session information in your database.  Check out the documentation, it's easy to set up: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

This is probably the better way to go, if you don't want to rely on cookies

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The database approach makes sense, of course. Somehow I have to generate some type of session key, however, otherwise the information stored in the database cannot be assigned to a certain user. So instead of using get-parameters for all userdata, at least a unique identifier has to be passed to the next controller. It's not that hard to do this manually, but to make my question more specific, I was really just wondering if there's already existing code to achieve this in an elegant way.

Comment: Storing session data in a database doesn't help. The session id still needs to be passed around via session cookie or get param

Comment: @Tim are you sure about that with CI?  I know the CI sessions does not use the native PHP sessions. I'm pretty sure the session ID does not get passed around via a session cookie if you use the database to store the information.  I admit, I could be wrong, and if you have any info to the contrary, please shoot it my way.

Comment: Tim is absolutely right. You can either use cookies, or use get parameters. Since HTTP is stateless, there really is no other way of "keeping a state" while navigating through several pages. If you install Firecookie for example you can actually track this behavour very well. Even if you use the database support, there will still be cookies.