# Codeigniter 3.x session is secure, use deprecated cart class or not?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, shopping-cart, cart

I got the solution that the Codeigniter 3.x session is secure because they doesn't use cookies.
([Codeigniter - Handle Sessions without cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421403/codeigniter-handle-sessions-without-cookies)).
And the **cart class** is deprecated and the official site says cart class may be removed in future updates. I think the cart class is deprecated because of CI 2.x session is not secure([Is it safe to use CodeIgniter shopping cart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077476/is-it-safe-to-use-codeigniter-shopping-cart)). Now the CI 3.0 session secure, my question is can I use cart class? It is secure? Any problems for using?

Comment: The cart class is going to be removed and will not be part of codeigniter 4. The cart class does not encourage e-commerce best practices. A cart should only be responsible for the product ids and quantity. Pricing and inventory come from your product table. Why? Pricing changes. Quantity changes. If inventory runs out, you need to remove it from the cart. If the price changes, then the line item totals change. The overall running order totals - cart product total, order discounts, shipping, tax, grand total - should be in a separate table / object.

Comment: I started my project in codeigniter and I have to manage cart in it and I am not gonna update core codeigniter, so deletion of cart class in future update won't affect me. I would like to know is there any security issues using cart class? thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You mix everything.
Session in CI3 are still using cookies, like any php framework,  and the cart class is safe . The cart class is deprecated by phylosophy but even better in CI3 because of the new CI3 session library .

Answer (score 0):

The detractors of the Cart class are overlooking its usefulness in persisting data from users who have yet to log in, but have added items to their cart. As such we can pull the session cart into the table that is going to hold the user's selections during checkout.
Every bit of information can be pulled from the products table so that regardless of what is in the session cart can corrected when the user logs in and her items are added to the cart's checkout process.

At that point as new products are added to cart the session cart can be ignored during checkout. Pricing, Attributes and any other product details should be coming from the server anyways, not from session.